# Pandas вычитание предыдущих значений с группировкой

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется такая таблица, необходимо с группировкой по компаниям вычитать предыдущие значения, но если значение получается положительным - записывать 0.
ранее мне подсказывали такое решение, но к сожалению оно выводит среднее значение, а необходимо просто затраты (x0 - x1, x1 - x2)

```
df2.groupby('Company').agg({'Signings': lambda x: x.diff(-1).mean()})
```

```
Date,Company,Signings
15,"ООО ""1""",82
15,"ООО ""2""",87
15,"ООО ""3""",78
15,"ООО ""4""",145
15,"ООО ""5""",69
15,"ООО ""6""",151
15,"ООО ""7""",82
15,"ООО ""8""",1
15,"ООО ""9""",61
15,"ООО ""10""",123
15,"ООО ""11""",166
15,"ООО ""12""",45
15,"ООО ""13""",90
15,"ООО ""14""",99
15,"ООО ""15""",81
15,"ООО ""16""",10
15,"ООО ""17""",75
16,"ООО ""1""",82
16,"ООО ""2""",87
16,"ООО ""3""",78
16,"ООО ""4""",145
16,"ООО ""5""",69
16,"ООО ""6""",151
16,"ООО ""7""",82
16,"ООО ""8""",1
16,"ООО ""9""",61
16,"ООО ""10""",123
16,"ООО ""11""",166
16,"ООО ""12""",45
16,"ООО ""13""",90
16,"ООО ""14""",99
16,"ООО ""15""",81
16,"ООО ""16""",10
16,"ООО ""17""",75
17,"ООО ""1""",72
17,"ООО ""2""",73
17,"ООО ""3""",65
17,"ООО ""4""",107
17,"ООО ""5""",39
17,"ООО ""6""",109
17,"ООО ""7""",78
17,"ООО ""8""",0
17,"ООО ""9""",27
17,"ООО ""10""",108
17,"ООО ""11""",143
17,"ООО ""12""",45
17,"ООО ""13""",90
17,"ООО ""14""",90
17,"ООО ""15""",81
17,"ООО ""16""",8
17,"ООО ""17""",5
```

Comment: А где тут среднее? Что-то сумбурно как-то. Распишите подробнее что вы хотите. Приведите пример результата.

Comment: исправил, неправильно код написал

Comment: тоже не совсем понял вопрос. вероятно, вам нужно что-то типа `df.groupby('Company').agg({'Signings': lambda x: x.diff().sum()})`

Comment: @strawdog Вроде автор вопроса хотел ещё чтобы положительные не учитывались в сумме )

Comment: @strawdog, я пробовал .sum(), но получается к сожалению не то, он складывает значения, а мне нужно, чтобы они были не в сумме

Comment: что такое предыдущие - за прошлую дату? напишите желаемый результат для пары характерных компаний

Comment: @splash58 например из компании 1, Date 15, вычитается компания 1, Date 16. из компании  2, Date 16, вычитается компания 2, Date 17. и так по порядку

Comment: так вы же говорите о вычитании последующих, а не предыдущих.

Comment: @CrazyElf есть подозрение, что автор вопроса сам толком не знает, чего хочет

Comment: вот вычли для компании 2 несколько раз, что с этими числами дальше делать?

Comment: @splash58 далее эти числа я буду писать в Prometheus, как метрику, а уже с этой метрикой работать и выводить в Grafana.

Comment: ValueError: Must produce aggregated value

Comment: `df['new'] = df.groupby('Company')['Signings'].apply(lambda x: x.diff())`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('Company')['Signings'].apply(lambda x: x.diff())
```